# Permission denied executing shell_exec (PhantomJS)

Tags: php, unix, phantomjs, shell-exec

I installed PhantomJS on my server and it's running great from the terminal. When I try to run form PHP using SHELL_EXEC, I get the following error:

```
phantomjs: Permission denied
```

I set the executable to 777 and I just don't know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it?, and where does it live? The user you're accessing phantomjs with may not have rights to something phantomjs needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your web user (I'm assuming it's `apache`) has +x permission on all the directories in the path for PhantomJS.

Assuming it's `/path/to/phantomjs/phantomjs`, apache (or its group) need to have +x permission on all `/path`, `/path/to`, `/path/to/phantomjs`.